# How to measure REST payload size?

Tags: spring, rest

i am using Spring-REST and JSON payload, is there an easy way to measure the payload size ?
My Rest controller returns a list of object, so i don't have a direct access to the JSON String sent to the client.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/films")
public class FilmController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Film> filmAll() {
        List<Film> films = filmDao.findAllManyToOneQueryDsl();
        return films;
    }
}
```

Comment: consider details.  baring further information, the length of your JSON payload can be calculated with StringUtils.length(jsonString).

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Content-Length` HTTP header, though it may or may not be there. It is supplied by the other side (client or server). You will also have to trust the other side to provide the correct value for `Content-Length`. Other than that, the payload is usually presented to you as a byte stream (or character stream). You can consume the stream and count the bytes (or characters).

Comment: Do you see any header ? Which headers do you see when you open the URL in your browser while network trace of F12 / developer tools is running ?

Comment: `Content-Length` is not a reliable source of payload size. If a request is being sent in chunks then you will not have this header.